# GStreamer element avdec_h264 fails to instantiate

Tags: c, gstreamer, h.264

I'm trying to build the following, well working pipeline in c code:

```
gst-launch-1.0 -v  udpsrc port=5000 \
 ! application/x-rtp,payload=96,media=video,clock-rate=90000,encoding-name=H264,sprop-parameter-sets=\"J2QAH6wrQCIC3y8A8SJq\\,KO4CXLA\\=\" \
 ! rtph264depay ! avdec_h264 \
 ! videoconvert ! autovideosink sync=false
```

Following the tutorial I instantiated the needed elements and checked if they have been created:

```
GstElement *pipeline, *source, *depay, *decode, *videoconvert, *sink;

// Initialize GStreamer
gst_init (NULL, NULL);

// Create the elements
source = gst_element_factory_make("udpsrc", "source");
depay = gst_element_factory_make("rtph264depay", "depay");
decode = gst_element_factory_make("avdec_h264", "decode");
videoconvert = gst_element_factory_make("videoconvert", "videoconvert");
sink = gst_element_factory_make("autovideosink", "sink");

// Create the empty pipeline
pipeline = gst_pipeline_new ("pipeline");

//Check if all elements have been created
if (!pipeline || !source || !depay || !decode || !videoconvert || !sink) {
    g_printerr ("Not all elements could be created.\n");
    return -1;
}
```

The code compiles successfully, the output when executing however is "Not all elements could be created." Further tries made me find the decoder element to be not created.

Where is my mistake? Why is the decoder element not created?

Im on OS X using gcc in the eclipse environment. Include path and linker flag is set.

Update:

Running the code with GST_DEBUG=3 as suggested by max taldykin outputs

```
0:00:00.011208000  5624 0x7f863a411600 INFO     GST_ELEMENT_FACTORY gstelementfactory.c:467:gst_element_factory_make: no such element factory "avdec_h264"!
0:00:00.011220000  5624 0x7f863a411600 INFO     GST_ELEMENT_FACTORY gstelementfactory.c:467:gst_element_factory_make: no such element factory "videoconvert"!
```

Comment: Try to run your application with `GST_DEBUG=1` environment variable set. This will give you some information on why element is not created.

Comment: I've updated the initial question. GST_DEBUG=1 doesn't have any output, but GST_DEBUG=3 does.

Comment: Are you sure that you are linking your executable to the same version of gstreamer as the one you are running from the command line? Also you can check `GST_PLUGIN_SYSTEM_PATH` env variable if gstreamer was installed in non-standard location.

Comment: You are right, I somehow had an outdated version installed. I have now installed the current version 1.2.3 of gstreamer including plugins. Still `GST_DEBUG=4` outputs `0:00:00.012627000 85728 0x7fc303411200 INFO     GST_ELEMENT_FACTORY gstelementfactory.c:456:GstElement *gst_element_factory_make(const gchar *, const gchar *): no such element factory "avdec_h264"!` get-inspect-1.0 however confirms the existence of the h264 decoder in the libav plugin.

Comment: Sorry, I'm out of ideas now. Maybe try to doublecheck `GST_PLUGIN_SYSTEM_PATH` or build your executable on some clean system.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. As you assumed my gstreamer installation was in a location different from the standard location. Adjusting the paths in eclipse solved the problem. Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: I also getting error in creating pipeline avdec_h264 no element in ios